# git branch for source files, merge only generated files into another branch

Tags: git, webpack

I have a Vue.js project which has a branch `src` for all the source files (`.vue`, `weback.config.js`, `package.json`, etc) which i do all of my dev work under, and under the `built` branch is where i keep all the "built" and "distribution" files at.

I generate the "built" files from under the `src` branch, but when i'm ready to push out the update I want to merge ONLY the built files generated under the `src` branch, into the `built` branch.

What is the best way of going about this?  I don't want to pollute my `built` branch with files from the `src` branch (specifically and only `assets/js/*.min.js` and `assets/css/*.min.css` fles) so my worry about merging from `src` to `built` would be that it would end up merging src files as.

I tried setting up the `src` branch so that it didn't track the `*.min.js` files hoping i could just checkout the `built` branch and commit there, but then i get "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout"

I might be making this more difficult than it needs to be, just hoping someone can point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I think you use git as a deployment tool. Git is not a good deployment tool. My advice is to separate development tools from deployment ones.

Comment: @phd yes kind of, it's based around hosting provider which actually uses git for the entire website version control.  So for local dev stuff it's easiest for me to just clone down my plugin in a subdirectory to work on stuff, then i can just push the built files to their git repo to update the actual website.  Their git implementation doesn't support submodules, and for time being i just manually copy over the built files into the built branch (for my plugin) and then can commit changes to push up to hosting provider

Comment: Ok, let's go git way. What about stashing untracked files with `git stash --include-untracked`, switch to the `built` branch, `git stash pop` to restore the generated files, add, commit and push?

Comment: Another, different approach: switch to the `built` branch from the very beginning, checkout all files from the last commit in `src`, build, remove source file, add, commit, push.